# Node.js - encrypt hard coded password with CSPRNG

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

I am using Node.js and Express.js to expose some APIs. Some passwords needs to be stored in a config file (json) which would then be used to connect to some other servers. Examples,

```
module.exports = {
    connection: {
        server: "abc"
          user: "user1",
        password: "p123"
    }
};
```

For security reasons, these passwords need to be encrypted (and subsequently decrypted by the service deployed in Express.js to connect to another server).

I looked at some Node.js encryption packages and found several npm packages like crypto-js, cryptr, simple-encryptor etc.

Now, the IT team has shared some security requirements which go as -

'Ensure that CSPRNG and not PRNG is used for JavaScript cryptography'

When I looked at these packages, I could not find whether they use CSPRNG or PRNG. Can someone please help me understand what exactly is the difference and which encryption/decryption package uses CSPRNG instead of PRNG?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your IT team is asking you to generate salts for when you encrypt the passwords. Bcrypt is probably the best crypto library. I dont think it will make a difference if you use PRNG or CSPRNG for generating the hash. See this post. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35576/do-i-need-to-use-a-csprng-when-creating-salts-for-user-accounts